# smarty Debugging Console

Tags: php, smarty

how to view Debugging Console not in popup window?
prefer in same window.
any idea?

Comment: {debug output="html"}

Answer (score 2):

Change debug template file `debug.tpl`. Just replace following code with something more suitable for your needs:

```
# _smarty_console.document.write('{$debug_output|escape:'javascript'}');
## write debug window directly in current document
document.write('{$debug_output|escape:'javascript'}');`
```

Comment: A little addition, debug.tpl can be found at Smarty root directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Firebug and FirePHP to redirect the debug information to the Firebig console: http://www.firephp.org/Wiki/Libraries/Smarty